# Having trouble with R's time series objects

Tags: r, csv, time-series, forecasting

I have a column of 84 monthly expenditures from 1/2004 - 12/2010, which in Excel looks like...

```
12247815.55
11812697.14
13741176.13
21372260.37
27412419.28
42447077.96
55563235.3
45130678.8
54579583.53
43406197.32
34318334.64
25321371.4
...(74 more entries)
```

I am trying to run an stl() from the forecast package on this series, and so I load the data:

```
d <- ts(read.csv("deseason_vVectForTS.csv",
header = TRUE),
start=c(2004,1),
end=c(2010,12),
frequency = 12)
```

(If I do header=FALSE it will absorb the first entry - 122...- as the header for the second column, and name the first column's header 'X')

But instead of my environment being populated with a `Time Series Object from 2004 to 2011` (as it has said before) it simply says `ts[1:84, 1]`.

Probably related is the fact that,

```
fit <- stl(d)
```

throws

```
Error in stl(d) : only univariate series are allowed.
```

despite the fact that

```
head(d)
[1] 12247816 11812697 13741176 21372260 27412419 42447078
```

and

```
d
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct
2004 12247816 11812697 13741176 21372260 27412419 42447078 55563235 45130679 54579584 43406197
("years 2005-2010 look exactly the same, and all rows have columns for Jan-Dec; it just doesn't fit on here neatly - just trying to show the object has taken the ts labeling structure.")
```

What am I doing wrong? As far as I know this is the same way I have been building my time series objects in the past...

Comment: What? http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/stlf The snippet is what it looks like in excel.

Comment: Kindly type ?forecast at the console and see the stl function in that package before responding again - definitely using forecast package's stl function.

Comment: stl() is not in the forecast package. It is part of the stats package. stlf() is in the forecast package.

Comment: This is helpful to the point of returning to the OP since the stlf function is throwing the same error.  (Unsure as to how I'm able to call stl() when stats package isn't loaded, but that really isn't the point of this question anyway.)

Comment: stlf() is calling stl(). You always have the stats package loaded when using R.

Comment: a) So why isn't the checkbox next to the stats package checked off on the package menu? b) why is the function saying this needs to be univariate when it clearly is (shown). I am doing this exactly as in your otext @RobHyndman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read.csv` reads in a matrix. If it only has one column, it is still a matrix. To make it a vector use

```
d <- ts(read.csv("deseason_vVectForTS.csv",
header = TRUE)[,1],
start=c(2004,1),
end=c(2010,12),
frequency = 12)
```

Also, please check your facts. `stl` is in the `stats` package, not the `forecast` package. This is easily checked by using `help(stl)`.